# Getting test valentin screen on app launch

Tags: ios, launch

I am getting a [black test valentine screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY6EW.png) on app launch.
I am using following libraries:

```
Google/SignIn 
FBSDKLoginKit 
FBSDKCoreKit
FBSDKShareKit 
FBSDKMessengerShareKit 
iOS-WebP 
FLAnimatedImage
NMRangeSlider 
LumberjackLauncher 
GoogleAppIndexing 
CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout 
Fabric 
Crashlytics 
Google/Analytics 
AdobeMobileSDK 
MPCoachMarks 
iCarousel 
You Tube
```

Please tell me due to which library I am getting this issue

Comment: Today again this screen is pushed in app for 5-10 min about 2o'clock.

Answer (score 1):

This screen is appear due to analytic SDK adobe omniture library. 
In JSon configuration file, following JSon urls are written:

"remotes": {
        "analytics.poi": "https://assets.adobedtm.com/b213090c5204bf94318f4ef0539a38b487d10368/scripts/satellite-568f7b6764746d25a900cb96.json",
        "messages": "https://assets.adobedtm.com/b213090c5204bf94318f4ef0539a38b487d10368/scripts/satellite-568f7b6564746d5bd3006fc0.json"
    }

In response of message url we are getting HTML text in payload module.

Just remove these URLs.